# is there any theory about why life evolved to have DNA with 4 different bases and not 6 or other number like in organisms created with artificial DNA?

Tags: genetics, evolution, dna, gene, molecular-evolution

If organisms can carry DNA with 6 bases which supposedly stores increased genetic information, why living organisms evolved to have DNA made of 4 bases and not 6 or other number? is there any theory about this, were the chemical process to reach those 2 additional bases much more complex or something?

Comment: There isn't a theory about that particular question as far I know of, but a possible answer is in the issue of complexity optimization in evolution. See, life is like a well-oiled machine-it always chooses **the simplest** and most reliable solutions to any problem it can face. What is simple in this case-a code of 4, 6, 8 or even more bases? Since it's double pair code the number must be even and 4 is the second even number-e.g. complex enough to provide redundancy but as simple as possible at the same time. The best optimization point possible. I hope this might serve as your answer.